# How to link to boost date_time

Tags: r, rcpp, boost-date-time

### Example

I have an Rcpp function where I would like to call `boost::posix_time::time_from_string()`.

I've taken the example code from the [boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) and translated it to a c++ function using Rcpp

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction(
  includes = '
    #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
  ',
  code = '
    void time_test() {
      std::string t = "2002-01-20 23:59:59.000";
      boost::posix_time::ptime pt(boost::posix_time::time_from_string(t));
      Rcpp::Rcout << "time from string: " << pt << std::endl;
    }
  ',
  depends = "BH"
)
```

However, this doesn't compile.

I've seen a few comments saying you need to link to `-lboost_date_time`, such as [this line](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rcppbdt/blob/master/src/toPOSIXct.cpp#L250) in Dirk's `RcppBDT` library

```
// The next function uses the non-stream-based parsing in Boost Date_Time
// and requires _linking_ with -lboost_date_time which makes the (otherwise
// header-only) build more complicate
// // [ [ Rcpp::export ] ]
// Rcpp::DatetimeVector charToPOSIXctNS(Rcpp::CharacterVector sv) {
//   ... code omitted ...
// }
```

### Question

How do you provide the appropriate links to `lboost_date_time`, other than including the `posix_time.hpp` header, so that one can use `time_from_string()`?

---

### Extra Info

It's possible to use other functions from the `boost/date_time` library, as demonstrated by this function, so what makes `time_from_string()` different?

```
cppFunction(
  includes = '
    #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
  ',
  code = '
    void time_test() {
      Rcpp::Datetime dt("2002-01-20 23:59:59.000");
      boost::posix_time::hours h( dt.getHours() );
      boost::posix_time::minutes m( dt.getMinutes() );
      boost::posix_time::seconds s( dt.getSeconds() );

      Rcpp::Rcout << h << std::endl;
      Rcpp::Rcout << m << std::endl;
      Rcpp::Rcout << s << std::endl;
    }
  ',
  depends = "BH"
)

time_test() 

# 12:00:00
# 00:59:00
# 00:00:59
```

Comment: See if my (old !!) `RcppBDT` -- which does a lot of stuff with Boost Date_Time -- or of course everybody's favourite converter `anytime` help.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you may have missed the part where _string conversion / formatting with Boost requires linking_ which is why the two aforementioned packages do not do that.  It's in the Boost Date_Time docs but somewhat hidden.  To them linking is normal; to use with the benefit and portability of header-only it is not.

Comment: In absence of a direct solution I'm actually using your [`stringToTime()`](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/blob/master/src/anytime.cpp#L199) function for now. (as I see you've bypassed `time_from_string()` in both `anytime` and `RcppBDT`)

Comment: You are free to use the Boost function _if and when you also link_.  Easiest to wrap your head around in a five-line C++ program at the command-line.  Not a constraint I impose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already found out, you need to *link* with boost at the system level. The BH package is not sufficient. So first you have to install the required boost library. On Debian (dervied) Linux systems this can be done via

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-date-time-dev
```

Then you need to tell R to add `-I/path/to/boost/headers` and `-L/path/to/boost/libraries -lboost_date_time` to the compiler flags. You can do this by setting appropriate environment variables:

```
library(Rcpp)

Sys.setenv(PKG_LIBS="-L/usr/lib -lboost_date_time", PKG_CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/include")

cppFunction(
  includes = '
    #include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
  ',
  code = '
    void time_test() {
      std::string t = "2002-01-20 23:59:59.000";
      boost::posix_time::ptime pt(boost::posix_time::time_from_string(t));
      Rcpp::Rcout << "time from string: " << pt << std::endl;
    }
  '
)
```

Notes:

- One could also define a Rcpp plugin for this.
- In my case `-I...` and `-L...` are unnecessary, since the library is installed in a standard location. One does need these flags in other cases, though.